# Power Automate save attachment as read-only

Tags: file, permissions, power-automate

I have a basic flow to save email attachments to a SharePoint folder, but I would like to extend this to save the attachment as a read-only file. Create File works fine, but the subsequent Send an HTTP request to SharePoint does nothing.
[image: HTTP request to SharePoint in flow]

I have also read that saving as read-only is not possible and saving as a checked-out file is a workaround. Also this I cannot get to work.
[image: Check out new file]

I guess my error in both flows is that I am not identifying the newly created file correctly. I have tried with both ItemId and Id, neither of which works.

Could someone please identify my error?

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn’t just modify the permissions on the library? Or is it a shared read/write stylr approach.

Comment: There will be other docs in the library and also my flow will save the original attachment as read only and also save a PDF open for comments, so I cannot use library permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution kindly provided by @yashag2255 on the Power Automate forum: Select "Documents" for Library name from the dropdown in the Check Out File action instead of providing a value manually or selecting the value from dynamic content.
[image]